# Device is reset when switching power sources

Tags: power-supply, batteries, diodes, reset, schottky

I use a home weather station. It is powered by two AA batteries (2 x 1.5 = 3.0 V nominal). The problem is that it eats more than 1 mA and that is quite a lot of power and I must buy a new pair of AA batteries quite often. That's why I tried to connect the device to my computer's power supply, because the computer is turned on for many hours every day. I connected it using two low-drop Schottky diodes this simple way:

[image]

All connections (cables) and batteries are always connected to the device, the only changing part is that the computer is sometimes on and sometimes off.

It is only a partial success, as I face two problems with it:

1. I used a low-drop diode 1N5817 which should have only .25 V drop, but still the voltage seems to be significantly reduced, because the station's LCD display looks like the batteries are old even when they are new. (Old AA batteries have lower voltage than new ones. I have a lower voltage too due to the diode. The weather station apparently doesn't like that.)
2. **The second and the main problem is that the weather station reset itself always on PC power-on. As I push power-on button on the PC, the weather station resets. And then works normally and its LCD display looks perfect.** When I turn-off PC, the station switches to battery power and continues to operate normally without problems.

I understand that the first problem is caused by the diode. But what is the cause of the second problem? Is it something with the low speed of diodes? Are the batteries in device always shocked by momentary reversed current on PC power-on? Or does PC power supply which need some time to stabilize its output and the weather station goes mad because of momentarily receiving too high voltage? Can a capacitor help to fix that?

My limitation is that the solution must be simple and cheap enough otherwise it would be better to buy a new pair of AA batteries 4-6 times a year as I do now.

Comment: Are you compensating in any way for the time it takes for the PSU to provide the power good signal? PC power supplies may provide strange output for some time and you can't rely on it until the power supply signals that it has stabilized. It would be a good idea to put some sort of switch which will only turn on the PC power when the PSU is ready.

Comment: What about a relay? If there is one which can work on 3.3 V.

Comment: I was more thinking about a transistor, since it would be easier to implement. The relay would nee more external components and am not sure that the line in question is actually capable of triggering a relay directly. If you can't have a transistor on the power supply directly, maybe a transistor based switch which would switch the relay? You could then use any of the available voltages to power the relay. Also, the signal is a 5 V signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you turn on the PC, the voltage jumps from 3V (or less) to 3.3V. That jump may be detected by the reset circuit in the weather station. Connect a resistor between the PC and its diode and connect a capacitor in parallel with the weather station. When you turn on the PC now, the capacitor will slowly charge to the higher voltage and hopefully the reset circuit won't detect it.

The capacitor can be big (1000uF or more for example), the resistor has to be big, but not big enough so as not to drop too much voltage. As the device uses 1mA, a 100Ohm resistor will drop about 0.1V, which should be OK.

As for your other problem - you should use a relay that is powered by the PC. When you turn on the PC, the relay energizes and switches to the PC. When the pc is turned off, the relay will turn off too and will switch back to the battery. The capacitor will hold enough power for the transition.

There should be relays that can be powered by 3.3V. If not, get a 5V relay and connect the coil (just the coil, connect R1 to 3.3V as usual) to the 5V rail in the PC.

A schematic including both of my suggestions. In this, the R1 can probably be up to 500Ohm as there is no more voltage drop from the diode.

[image: schematic]

Comment: Thanks, I am going to check it. I mean there probably really is some kind of automatic reset-circuit which resets the device on power-on. It makes sense. Unfortunatelly 3.3V relays aren't present in our local shop.

Comment: @AlKepp, in that case get a 5V relay and connect its coil to the 5V in the PC, while still connecting the contacts to 3.3V.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices can be sensitive to rapid changes in VDD, even within what would otherwise be normal operating conditions.  When VDD is 2.2 volts (as it might be when running off less-than-perfect batteries), a signal which is supposed to be high will only have a level of 2.2 volts or below.  If VDD suddenly increases to 2.9 volts, a 2.2-volt signal might not be high enough to be regarded as a valid logic high.  This could cause weird behaviors within the device.

You may be able to fix the problem in your case by adding a resistor in series with the PC power supply connection.  Such a resistor should be small enough not to drop more than 0.3 volts under expected loading conditions (lest you drain your batteries needlessly) but may serve to reduce the rate at which VDD rises.  Note that most parts are only bothered by very rapid changes in VDD, so slowing things down even a little bit may help.